# How to bind a ListView to multiple collections stored in a single ViewModel in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have 2 collections I want to bind to a separate `GridViewColumn` in a `ListView`:

```
public class EffectView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ObservableCollection<Effect> effects;
    public ObservableCollection<Effect> Effects
    {
        get { return this.effects; }
        set
        {
            this.effects = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "Effects" );
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<EffectDescription> descriptions;
    public ObservableCollection<EffectDescription> Descriptions
    {
        get { return this.descriptions; }
        set
        {
            this.descriptions = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "Descriptions" );
        }
    }
}
```

I can do this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectView.Effects}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                            Header="Name" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Opacity}"
                            Header="Opacity" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ?}"
                            Header="Description" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But then everything is scoped to `EffectView.Effects`, but I want the default scope to be `EffectView` so I can easily assign multiple collections to the `ListView`.

Something like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectView}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Effects Path=Name}"
                            Header="Name" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Effects Path=Opacity}"
                            Header="Opacity" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Descriptions Path=Usage}"
                            Header="Description" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` of a ListView is *the collection* whose items will appear in the list. So think for a moment about what you're asking the ListView to do:

- As a source collection, use something that isn't a collection, but contains them
- For each row in the list, display an item from one collection, and an item from the other collection

Pay attention to that second point: every row must display some item from the Events collection and some item from the Descriptions collection.

**Which item shall it pick from each? What's the relationship between the items in the two collections?**

It *appears* that what you really need is a collection of objects that contains *both* an Event and a Description. You can then bind to that collection to display elements of both entities. Roughly, something like this:

```
public class EffectView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    ObservableCollection<EffectsAndDescriptions> effects;
    public ObservableCollection<EffectAndDescriptions> Effects
    {
        get { return this.effects; }
        set
        {
            this.effects = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged ( "EffectsAndDescriptions" );
        }
    }

}

internal class EffectsAndDescriptions
{
    public Effect Effect { get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can bind to the EffectsAndDescriptions collection (note this assumes the DataContext of the ListView's *parent* is `EffectView`)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EffectsAndDescriptions}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Effect.Name}"
                            Header="Name" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Effect.Opacity}"
                            Header="Opacity" />

            <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description.Usage}"
                            Header="Description" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not really possible. ItemsSource expects to be passed something that, at a minimum, implements IEnumerable. Even if you implemented IEnumerable on your EffectView, you would need to wrap Effect and EffectDescription into a single object to return.

You could bind your ListView to your Effects collection, then use a custom IValueConverter to take the Effect and return a description. But I'm not sure this would fit your situation.

Your best bet would be to include a wrapper object (i.e. EffectWithDescription) that includes both your Effect and your EffectDescription. Then expose a collection of EffectWithDescription objects. You'd need to ensure that this new collection is keep in sync with the other collections though.