# How do I populate listview in 2 columns from 2 arrays in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I have a listview item

(XAML)

```
<ListView Name="myListView" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" Margin="12,27,428,12">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Test1}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Column2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Test2}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
```

And want to fill it with 2 different arrays

```
string[] ApplicationNames
string[] ClassNames
```

but I'm having difficulty doing so. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm using WPF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412797/how-to-bind-a-listview-to-multiple-collections-stored-in-a-single-viewmodel-in-w).

P.S. If you are developing UI in XAML, you are developing a `WPF Application`, not `Winforms`. `Winforms` applications are created by choosing `Windows Forms Application` when choosing the project type in `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Thanks also for explaining the difference between WPF and WinForms!

Answer (score 1):

XAML:

```
 <ListView Name="ResultListView">
      <ListView.View>
           <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ApplicationName }" Header="File" />
              <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClassName }"     Header="Location" />
           </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

MyObject.cs

```
class MyObject
{
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<MyObject> results = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
//Populate some data into results here
ResultListView.ItemsSource =results;
```